# vim/xterm: thin vertical highlighted bars on some lines at extreme right side of screen

Tags: vim, arch-linux, xterm, highlighting

I use vim in an xterm. Just recently I have noticed the appearance of thin vertical highlighted bars on some lines at extreme right side of xterm. They are not tied to the text, for they remain in the same relative positions when I scroll the text, and they are outside vim's text area for I cannot move the cursor onto one.

They are about half the width of the cursor, and about half again as high, so there is no gap between 2 consecutive such. They appear and disappear for no apparent reason, and seem to have no purpose or significance.

Could someone kindly explain what they are?

Comment: could you take a screenshot ? it would much easier to understand :)

Comment: Fraid not, today its choosing not to do it

Comment: That kinda makes it difficult for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like colorcolumn.

> 'colorcolumn' is a comma separated list of screen columns that are highlighted with ColorColumn. Useful to align text. Will make screen redrawing slower. The screen column can be an absolute number, or a number preceded with '+' or '-', which is added to or subtracted from 'textwidth'.

This was added in VIM 7.3 AFAIK, however in prior versions there are ways of achieving similar effects.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its not cc, I use that in a mapping to highlight the cursor location, and its set to red, this was yellow, and its width only half that of cc.  I haven't seen the effect since the day before I queried it, think I did something by accident that did not persist beyond that session.